# what is the shebang we use for python script in windows?

Tags: python, scripting, shebang

Shebang for python script in linux is as :-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

What would be the shebang for windows ?

Comment: On win32, file extensions are used to determine interpreter, not shebangs; so there doesn't exist any Windows equivalent, and doesn't need to.

Comment: You may want to read [Shebang Lines](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines)